# How do I get the ID of a JQuery item mid-function?

Tags: jquery, css

I am attempting to dynamically change the background image of some menu options when the user hovers/clicks on the menu item. To do this I am using the JQuery .css() method to change background-image. When the user clicks on a menu item I am changing the background image for all menu items back to their original state, and then modifying the one clicked. How do I do this with JQuery? (The image files are all saved in the same manner "/PictureLibrary/NavBarShortcuts/'menuItemID'.gif" and "/PictureLibrary/NavBarShortcuts/'menuItemID'Active.gif") The image used should reflect the state of the menu item. Since I assign the default background image dynamically when I generate them using PHP I don't believe that I can use multi-class CSS to assign the background images, due to the lack of CSS for the non-active class. Although I may be wrong.

Heres what I have:

```
$('.menuItem').css( "background-image", "url(../PictureLibrary/NavBarShortcuts/PRODUCTIDHERE.gif)");
$('.menuItem active').css( "background-image", "url(../PictureLibrary/NavBarShortcuts/PRODUCTIDHEREActive.gif)");
```

I have multiple menu items all with different ID's generated dynamically from a database. I.E.

```
<div class="menuItem" id="product1">
//I need to change these background images dynamically.
</div>
<div class="menuItem" id="product2">
//I need to change these background images dynamically.
</div>
<div class="menuItem" id="product3">
//I need to change these background images dynamically.
</div>
<div class="menuItem" id="product4">
//I need to change these background images dynamically.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menuItem').each(function(i){
        $(this).css("background-image", "url(../PictureLibrary/NavBarShortcuts/"+this.id+".gif)");
    });
    $('.menuItem').click(function(){
        $(this).siblings().filter(".active")
            .removeClass("active")
            .each(function(i){
                $(this).css("background-image", "url(../PictureLibrary/NavBarShortcuts/"+this.id+".gif)");
            });
        $(this).addClass("active")
            .css( "background-image", "url(../PictureLibrary/NavBarShortcuts/"+this.id+"Active.gif)");
    });
});
```

Check this fiddle, through firebug or something similar, to see the style changing (because the images doesn't exist, so it can't load them): http://jsfiddle.net/Y9HzN/

Comment: This works, with minor tweaking and placement so that it works with the other parts of the script. Thanks a lot! Good answer!

Answer (score 0):

Don´t use jQuery for this matter, use CSS instead. You can easyly achieve the same goal.

Suppose that you have:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">MenuA</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">MenuB</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">MenuB</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav > ul li > a:hover {
   background-color: orange;
}
```

Comment: The problem I had with CSS is that each Menu Item is going to have a different background, and the whole idea is that as much of the website as possible should be dynamic, and is mainly imported from a database of company products, and as soon as I start hard-coding ID's into the CSS then I'm limiting myself.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, though it's not tested:

```
$('.menuItem').hover(function(){
    this.src = this.src.replace('.jpg', 'Active.gif');
}, function(){
    this.src = this.src.replace('Active.jpg','.gif');
});
```

This assumes that the `src` is set to the appropriate URI in the first place (and simply inserts, or removes, the `Active` string as appropriate). If you need to use the actual `id` each time:

```
$('.menuItem').hover(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', "/PictureLibrary/NavBarShortcuts/" + this.id + ".gif"
}, function(){
    $(this).attr('src', "/PictureLibrary/NavBarShortcuts/" + this.id + "Active.gif"
});
```

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).
- [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).